# iPhone app exited abnormally with exit status 13

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, cydia

I compiled an app from Xcode, and put the app into the `/Applications` folder in my iPhone, but when I click the app icon, it unexpectedly quits.

the info in syslog is

> exited abnormally with exit status 13

how do I fix this?

My intention is run my app as `root`.  I used [this link](http://exilesofthardware.blogspot.com/2013/01/) but syslog still showed **"exited abnormally with exit status 13"**.  I think it is a problem with the code signing, but when I `chmod 755 myapp`, it runs, but only as the normal user.

Comment: You just copied app bundle to iOs apps directory, no fancy magic to avoid signing and protection techniques ?

Comment: Please tell me which one provisioning you r u using either developer or distribution ?

Comment: Please describe what you did as detailed as possible at the question itself (use edit option) instead of the comments.

Comment: @A-Live @ Dharmbir Choudhary I use the Xcode 4.6.1 and I faked Code Sign by adding a certificate -"iPhone Developer"in Keychain Access and moding the info.plist and SDKSetting.plist of Xcode，finally ,I change the value of "Code Signing Identity"  into "Don't code sign",so what should I do next?, my intention is run my app as root,I use the http://exilesofthardware.blogspot.com/2013/01/ios-run-application-with-root-privileges.html ,but syslog showed "exited abnormally with exit status 13",I think it is a problem about the code signing ,but when I “chmod 755 myapp”,it works ,but as normal user.

Answer (score 0):

try using ldid you can get it from here

[Download ldid](https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid)

use the command as such, MyApp is the name of your own app

```
ldid -S MyApp
```

Comment: Signs the application in order for it to run and gets rid of the need for an Apple Developer account.